# iPhone's Pasteboard not recognizing a URL

Tags: iphone, url, uiwebview, clipboard

I want my app to recognize if the current contents of the Clipboard are a URL, and if it is, I want it to load that URL into a web-view. 
I'm using the following statement to do this checking:

```
 if ([pasteboard containsPasteboardTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.url-name"]]) 
     ...code to load the URL into the webView
```

but its not working - the IF statement always returns as FALSE, even when the clipboard's contents are clearly a URL. 
Strangely enough though, when I remove this IF statement and just go ahead and load the URL I read from the Clipboard into the webView it works perfectly well. So its definitely just the IF statement that's not working for some reason.

Here's the full code:

```
// executed on a Button-click:
-(IBAction) showClipBoard {
    pasteboard = nil;  // resetting the pasteBoard each time
    pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSURL *tempURL = pasteboard.URL;    

    //Check the pasteboard's value-type:
    if ([pasteboard containsPasteboardTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.url-name"]]) {
      NSLog(@"URL is: %@", pasteboard.string);       
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: pasteboard.string];
      NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
      [webView loadRequest:req];   
  }
else 
    NSLog(@"=NOT a valid web-address");

NSString *tempString = [pasteboard valueForPasteboardType:@"public.utf8-plain-text"];

// Show the URL in a text-view box called "clipText":
clipText.text = tempString;
```

}

Anyone see what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out by now, but, I ran into the same issue & the following worked for me :-

```
if ([pasteboard containsPasteboardTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.url"]]) 
 ...code to load the URL into the webView
```